# Overlay the boundary of the segmented region on the original image Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to segment an object from an image. The object is a leaf as shown in the left image. I did segment it and got this right image:

[image]

Now I am trying to overlay the boundary of the segmented region contour from the binary image on the original image, so I can get similar image to this one:

[image]

I am not really sure how to do this. I tried to trace the boundaries of the binary image and then post over the main image but couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very easy to do.  Simply use your mask and calculate the perimeter of your mask using [`bwperim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html).  Once you find those edges, you can use these locations and set the pixels in the original image to yellow.  To do this, simply extract each colour plane of the original image, then use the pixels that are along the perimeter of your mask to index into each colour plane and set these to a particular channel value.  To make this yellow, you'd set the red and green values to 255 along the perimeter, and the blue values to be 0 along the perimeter too.  If you want to combine all of these into a single image, use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) and go along the third dimension.  In other words, supposing your binary image is stored in `mask`, your original image in `im`, you would do this (assuming a colour image):

```
perim = bwperim(mask, 8); %// Get perimeter of the mask
red = im(:,:,1); %// Extract the colour planes of the original image
green = im(:,:,2);
blue = im(:,:,3);
red(perim) = 255; %// Set those pixels in the perimeter to yellow
green(perim) = 255;
blue(perim) = 0;
out = cat(3, red, green, blue); %// Make an output image
figure;
imshow(out);
```

---

`out` should contain the original image with the perimeter of the leaf overlaid on top in yellow.

Comment: Looks like another useful tool `bwperim`! Thanks! +1

Comment: @Divakar - cool!  Now I'm teaching you stuff!  I found out about `bwperim` by accident one day!

Answer (score 0):

As of Matlab version R2015a there is a function for you to do this within the image processing toolbox:
[visboundaries](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/visboundaries.html)

I think the documentation provided in the link should be quite easy to understand :)